# Generating function call graph

Tags: c, gcc, call-graph

I am using the [egypt](http://www.gson.org/egypt/) tool to visualize call graphs of c files.

Using the option `--include-external` one can see the calls to functions that are defined externally (in libraries, other project .c files etc.)

I am wondering if there is any way to know in which file is the external function declared? 
Not specifically to the tool, but in general is it feasible during this stage of the compilation to know the location of the function to be called?

Comment: You mean which headerfile the function is declared in, or which source file was used to build the library? [I don't really know the answer either way, just wondering which you mean]

Comment: Good point, I was thinking about that also, eventually I want the implementation of the function not the definition.

Comment: If it's a library function, then the "connection" between source and actual code is lost. I've used `cscope` to find stuff in projects, and it's got pretty good integration with emacs and vi on Linux at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse CDT. Configure the include paths and library paths . You can then navigate your functions easily also it provides call hierarchy.